# How do I print on screen the value of a counter masm32

Tags: assembly, x86, 32-bit, masm32

I'm trying to print the value of a counter that increments inside a while loop I made, this is just a part of a bigger function I'm working on for a project, here's how I'm increasing the value of the counter variable and trying to print it, because of the way I'm calling the printf function I believe I need to push char[] variables with what I want to print onto the stack, I've tried pushing the counter values directly to print (using "push edx" directly instead of storing the address of a char[] variable and then pushing it) and it just spits out random numbers probably the memory address of the value or something, the way the print function call is set up works properly when I print char[] variables for which I've already specified the content when I declare them before the _asm tag (for example " char text[4] = "%s\n" "), I would really appreciate your help, I can post the whole function too if needed be.

```
        _calcGravedad:
        mov edx, G        // G stored in edx
        inc edx           //increases edx
        mov G, edx        //returns edx to G

    //here I try to convert my int G variable (the counter) into a char[]
    //so i can print it, I'm not sure of this part, it doesnt work
        lea eax, G          //stores memory addres of G into eax
        push eax             //push eax into the stack
        call byte ptr _itoa_s //calls the conversion function from c
        pop edx               //transfers the result to edx
        mov gravedad, edx     //moves the result to a char[] variable

    //here's the print function call
        lea eax, gravedad    //get address of gravedad
        push eax           //push it into the stack
        lea eax, texto     //push the print format "%s\n" onto the stack
        push eax           //    
        call DWORD ptr printf   //calls the print function
        pop edx                  //cleans the stack
        pop edx                  //
```

Comment: You should call the OS kernel via a system call, `write`

Comment: @self : Making a _syscall_ directly on Win32/Win64 platforms is generally frowned upon since MS has been known to change them over time. Calling functions in kernel32.dll and user32.dll that wrap the system calls is preferred, or in this case calling the _C_ library that is another layer of abstraction. Maybe you were thinking more along the lines of Linux/BSD etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure why you need the address of `G` rather than its value, or why you need two library calls. Why not pass your counter value straight to `printf` along with a `%d` format instead of the `%s` format?

I don't have working masm but this should illustrate (MSVC):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int G = 42;
    char *fmt = "%d\n";
    __asm {
        mov eax,G       ;counter value
        push eax
        mov eax,fmt     ;format argument
        push eax
        call printf
        pop eax
        pop eax        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Console output:

```
42
```

You might need a different `mov` instruction for the format string, such as `lea eax,fmt` or `mov eax,offset fmt`. Note too, you don't need to qualify the library function calls as you do.

Comment: Thank you very much! it worked! and you're right about the way I do the function calls as well.